# Grouping by value with separation of the output

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa

I have a this type of data:

```
| company_id | role_id |  
| 1          | 1       |
| 2          | 2       |
| 1          | 2       |
```

Here's my query which selects one company id and passed as an argument role id.

```
SELECT company_id AS companyId, COUNT(role_id) AS usersNumber 
FROM companies
WHERE role_id = :userId
GROUP BY companyId
```

Where `:userId` is an argument passed from JPA.

Which produces something like this:

```
| company_id | passed_role_id_count |
| 1          | 1                    |
| 2          | 1                    |
```

What I want to achieve is to have the output like this:

```
| company_id | first_role_count | second_role_count |
| 1          | 1                | 1                 |
| 2          | 0                | 1                 |
```

Is it possible to have the output like this? Or maybe is it better to select all from DB and then group using Java Streams?

Comment: Use `case` expressions to do _conditional aggregation_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a filtered aggregation:

```
SELECT company_id AS companyId, 
       COUNT(*) filter (where role_id = 1) AS first_role_count, 
       COUNT(*) filter (where role_id = 2) AS second_role_count
FROM companies
WHERE role_id = :userId
GROUP BY companyId
```

Comment: @Forin. . . This is the best way to write this code in Postgres.  If you don't want the filtering on `:userId`, you can remove it but that is part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

With the hint from @jarlh I managed to solve my problem:

```
SELECT eu.company_id,
   SUM(CASE WHEN eu.role_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "first_role",
   SUM(CASE WHEN eu.role_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "second_role"
FROM users eu
GROUP BY eu.company_id;
```